# How to prevent lxml from adding a default doctype

Tags: python, lxml, libxml2

lxml seems to add a default doctype when one is missing in the html document.

See this demo code:

```
import lxml.etree
import lxml.html


def beautify(html):
    parser = lxml.etree.HTMLParser(
        strip_cdata=True,
        remove_blank_text=True
    )

    d = lxml.html.fromstring(html, parser=parser)
    docinfo = d.getroottree().docinfo

    return lxml.etree.tostring(
        d,
        pretty_print=True,
        doctype=docinfo.doctype,
        encoding='utf8'
    )


with_doctype = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>With Doctype</title>
</head>
</html>
"""

# This passes!
assert "DOCTYPE" in beautify(with_doctype)

no_doctype = """<html>
<head>
  <title>No Doctype</title>
</head>
</html>"""

# This fails!
assert "DOCTYPE" not in beautify(no_doctype)

# because the returned html contains this line
# <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# which was not present in the source before
```

---

How can I tell lxml to not do this?

This issue was originally raised here:
https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/845

Quoting a [comment on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/42rb90/comparing_execution_time_of_pretty_printing_an/czclx15) as it might be helpful:

> lxml is based on libxml2, which does this by default unless you pass the option `HTML_PARSE_NODEFDTD`, I believe. Code [here](https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2/blob/master/HTMLparser.c#L4777).
>
> I don't know if you can tell lxml to pass that option though.. libxml has python bindings that you could perhaps use directly but they seem really hairy.
>
> EDIT: did some more digging and that option does appear in the lxml soure [here](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd#L20). That option does exactly what you want but I'm not sure how to activate it yet, if it's even possible.

Comment: The `HTML_PARSE_NODEFDTD` option isn't handled in the [HTMLParser constructor](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/lxml-3.4/src/lxml/parser.pxi#L1625), so you're probably out of luck.

Comment: @nwellnhof Maybe we could work out a fix for this, and create a PR @ lxml? The option is present [here](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/93ec66f6533995a7742278f9ba14b925149ac140/src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd#L19-L20) though.

Comment: I also [asked this question on the lxml mailing list](https://mailman-mail5.webfaction.com/pipermail/lxml/2016-August/007738.html). No solution yet.

Comment: FWIW, the libxml2 Perl bindings [do expose this option](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod#no_defdtd), as does [libxml-ruby](http://xml4r.github.io/libxml-ruby/rdoc/LibXML/XML/HTMLParser/Options.html).

Comment: I don't think the fix for this would be too hard, but I just don't have enough experience with cython etc. so won't be able to compile it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this in lxml, but I've created a [Pull Request on lxml](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/issues/203) which adds a `default_doctype` boolean to the `HTMLParser`.

Once the code gets merged in, the parser needs to be created like so:

```
parser = lxml.etree.HTMLParser(
    strip_cdata=True,
    remove_blank_text=True,
    default_doctype=False,
)
```

Everything else stays the same.